# ActionView::Template::Error: bootstrap_and_overrides.css isn't precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link that got this error. I already ran precompile on production, this still occurs. The problem is it works on staging, which is in the same server as the production setup. Why is this happening?

Comment: Fixed via this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123928/rails-3-2-css-not-being-precompiled